# Safari doesn't want to autoplay video. How to fix this?

Tags: video, safari, html5-video, autoplay

I've already tried nearly everything but can't find the solution for how to make Safari autoplay video at the start of the webpage.

```js
<script>
 
     var loopCount = 0;

     document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
      if (this.currentTime == 0)
      ++loopCount;
      if (loopCount == 20)
      this.pause();
});

</script>

<script>
 
var promise = document.querySelector('#bgvid').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback
    }).then(() => {
        // Auto-play started
    });
}

</script>

<script> 
 
 
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 113) {
   document.getElementById('bgvid').pause();
  }
 });
 
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 112) {
   document.getElementById('bgvid').play(); 
  }  
 });
</script>

         
<!--------- Script Video End ---------->
```

```css
#bgvid {
 object-fit: cover;
}

.video-container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
}

video {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
}

.video-container::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: #1b1b1b;
      opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
      <a id="home"></a>
      <div class="wrapper">


            <!--------------- hero section starts here --------------->

            <div class="video-container">
             
                  <video preload="metadata" poster="/img/prevideo1.jpg" autoplay   muted="true" loop playsinline id="bgvid">
                   
                    <source src="videobg%20-%20converted%20with%20Clipchamp.webm" type="video/webm" alt="Your browser does not support the video tag.">
                   
                   <source src="videobg.mp4" type="video/mp4" alt="Your browser does not support the video tag."> 
                    
     <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>  
         
                  </video>
            </div>
```

Here is the link to the page:  http://avelitest.epizy.com/index.html

However, in Chrome everything works well. I just don't understand what's wrong with it. Thanks for your help!)

Answer (score 0):

"Safari...uses an automatic inference engine to block media elements with sound from auto-playing by default on most websites."

https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

Comment: I've already tried this and also I tried to use attribute 'muted' which also didn't help.

Comment: You've already tried what?  The page I linked to says that Safari blocks auto-play.

Comment: You wrote to me that Safari blocks "media elements with sound"  from auto-play because of the sound in it but in my case the sound is off and there is no sound at all in this video. What I meant is that I tried to allow autoplay for the website in Safari preferences but it still won't autoplay.

Comment: I'm sorry, somehow I misread your question as "Safari doesn't want to autoplay AUDIO."  However, Safari also blocks autoplay video without explicit permission, as the article says:  "Websites should assume any use of <video> or <audio> requires a user gesture click to play."  On the other hand, if you've allowed autoplay in preferences, it should autoplay.  My video (with an audio track) autoplays when I set the preferences to allow it: <video autoplay controls src=mymovie.mp4></video>  Try making a skeleton page, with nothing on it but the necessary elements and the video tag.

Comment: Okay, so I tried to do that but it still don't work. However when I run website directly from the laptop and not from the hosting everything works well in Safari.

Comment: (1) When you say you tried "all that", do you mean you tried making a skeleton page, with nothing on it but the <video> tag, and you allowed Autoplay in Safari preferences, and the video still won't autoplay?  (2) When you run the problem page over the web, will the video play if you click the Play button?